# I am trying to create a validation rule to verify the field 'Occupancy' so that a Booking is only active based on the Occupany

Tags: formula-field, validation, system-admin

[image]I am trying to create a validation rule on my Booking object so that the Booking can only be active if the Occupancy status on the Booking is either `In House` or `Temporarily Vacated` or `Blocked out` or `Reserved`.

The Active Booking field is a formula checkbox type with the formula

```
AND(check_in_date__cc <=TODAY().  Check_out_date__cc.>=TODAY()
```

My validation rule 'Verify Occupancy' (below) keeps getting errors.

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Thanks if anyone can resolve.

```
IF(

AND(

Active_Booking__c = TRUE,

 
AND(

ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'In House'),

AND(

ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Reserved'),

AND(

ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Temporary check out/returning'),

AND(

ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'BLOCKED OUT'),

true, false))))))
```

Comment: You have terminated the `AND` & `IF` conditions incorrectly. It has to be `IF(AND(Active_Booking__c = TRUE, AND(ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'In House'), AND(ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Reserved'), AND(ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Temporary check out/returning'), ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'BLOCKED OUT'))))),true, false)`. Read more about `IF` formula [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks @arut.  Both of these work in the sense that they do not return any error messages but when I test a booking and set the occupancy to Cancelled then the Active Booking checkbox remains true?

Comment: Validation rules only verify if the data entered meets the specified requirements before the record can be saved. They don't update any existing field. You can read more about validation rules [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm&type=5). The value of `Active Booking` checkbox is determined by the formula you have defined on this field. So, you need to tweak this formula to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The **if** condition in formula builder expect you to return for true condition and false condition. You have defined the condition but not returned any value for true/false condition. Instead you had written inside **AND** which is wrong in your case. Also, you can remove all the **AND** condition and keep one.

```
IF(
    AND(
            Active_Booking__c = TRUE,
            ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'In House'),
            ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Reserved'),
            ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'Temporary check out/returning'),
            ISPICKVAL(Occupancy__c, 'BLOCKED OUT')
        ), 
    true, false
)
```

Comment: Thanks @sanket kumar.  Both of the above work in the sense that they do not bring any error messages but when I test a booking and set the occupancy to Cancelled then the Active Booking checkbox remains true?

Comment: you can eliminate the IF, true, false altogether as AND returns a Boolen